# Vector (polygon) to raster conversion

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I am trying to convert my vector file (polygons) to raster by assigning a 10x10 size to the pixel cells.
However it gives me this error:

[image]

I used as "Field to use for a burn - in value" a column of the vector attributes (integer number).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you have a rather small vector dataset in EPSG:4326 coordinate system and you ask to use a pixel size of 10 by 10 degrees that is about 1200 km by 1200 km. It may be something else. Show the orginfo report about your source data and complete gdal_rasterize command that you usedl

Comment: The reference system of the project is: WGS 84/UTM zone 32N (EPSG: 32632) while the reference system of the vector to be converted is WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N (EPSG:32632 - Projected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the limits in metres, not degrees (estensione risultato)